# How to change javascript code to typescript in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new in angular programming and I searched and couldn't find something that could help me and I have no idea what should I search for this problem. I'm using a template for my project [Here is that template](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideDownBoxMenu/#) and there is a javascript file in that template :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'170px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');
                
                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and I want to convert the javascript file to typescript and use this part in a directive like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[appListItemsShow]'
})
export class ListItemsShowDirective {

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2) { }
  @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseenter(eventData: Event) {
    console.log("mouse enter");
    var $elem = $(this);
    $elem.find('img')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({
        'width': '170px',
        'height': '170px',
        'left': '0px'
      }, 400, 'easeOutBack')
      .andSelf()
      .find('.sdt_wrap')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({ 'top': '140px' }, 500, 'easeOutBack')
      .andSelf()
      .find('.sdt_active')
      .stop(true)
      .animate({ 'height': '170px' }, 300, function () {
        var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
        if ($sub_menu.length) {
          var left = '170px';
          if ($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index() + 1)
            left = '-170px';
          $sub_menu.show().animate({ 'left': left }, 200);
        }
      });
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave(eventData: Event) {    
    console.log("mouse leave");
      var $elem = $(this);
      var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
      if ($sub_menu.length)
        $sub_menu.hide().css('left', '0px');

      $elem.find('.sdt_active')
        .stop(true)
        .animate({ 'height': '0px' }, 300)
        .andSelf().find('img')
        .stop(true)
        .animate({
          'width': '0px',
          'height': '0px',
          'left': '85px'
        }, 400)
        .andSelf()
        .find('.sdt_wrap')
        .stop(true)
        .animate({ 'top': '25px' }, 500);
  }
}
```

And I get errors like this:

```
$elem.find(...).stop(...).animate(...).andSelf is not a function
    at ListItemsShowDirective.mouseenter (list-items-show.directive.ts:22)

$elem.find(...).stop(...).animate(...).andSelf is not a function
    at ListItemsShowDirective.mouseleave (list-items-show.directive.ts:50)
```

What am I suppose to do? How can I convert this js to ts to use it in my directive?
(by the way I'm using this directive in li element which is in ul element with id='sdt_menu')
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Not related to your question, but don't use jquery with angular, as angular needs full control over the DOM itself. Angular does animations as well.

Comment: @Celsiuss thanks :) I don't know what is $(this) refer to and is var $elem equals ElementRef in angular?